# Change DNS suffix on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I attempting to deploy a Windows VM in Azure that will be running DNS for resolving a private zone in my VNet.  I have created the VNet and set the IP address of the VM as the DNS server for the VNet.  Since I have configured the VNet with a private DNS server, the VM gets the placeholder suffix of reddog.microsoft.com.  I install DNS on the VM and create my forward and reverse zones.  Since the VMs in the VNet will not be domain joined, I configure DDNS to allow unsecure updates.  Outside of manually registering a record for the VM running DNS, I am unable to get it to register records.  When I try to change the DNS suffix on the NIC, as soon as I click OK on the NIC properties window, my connection is killed and I am no longer able to get back into the VM.  The only thing I can do at this point is to destroy it and start over.  What am I missing here?  Will I have to manually register records for anything I put into the VNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

From this document about [Name resolution that uses your own DNS server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server):

> When you are using Azure-provided name resolution, Azure Dynamic Host
> Configuration Protocol (DHCP) provides an internal DNS suffix
> (.internal.cloudapp.net) to each VM. This suffix enables hostname
> resolution because the hostname records are in the
> internal.cloudapp.net zone. When you are using your own name
> resolution solution, **this suffix is not supplied to VMs** because it
> interferes with other DNS architectures (like domain-joined
> scenarios). Instead, Azure provides a non-functioning placeholder
> (reddog.microsoft.com).

It says that your custom DNS suffix is not supplied to VMs because it interferes with other DNS architectures (like domain-joined scenarios). Moreover, Azure doesn't have the credentials to directly create records in your DNS servers. Azure leaves the primary DNS suffix blank, and you can set the suffix in the VM as the picture below:

[image]

After changing the DNS suffix, you will restart the VM, then you will see a new DNS suffix in the DNS Suffix Search List in the output of prompt commands.

[image]

Go to the DNS server, you will see the DNS records updated. Before this, make sure you have enabled the Nonsecure and secure of the Dynamic updates in the zone properties.

Comment: That is a MAJOR difference.  It is documented that having domain joined machines is really a different scenario.  I am trying to do it without have an Active Directory domain.

Comment: Yes, this helped.  My problem was that I was trying to edit the suffix information on the NIC instead of the computer properties.  Once I realized my mistake, made the change on the DNS server itself and then restarted...the A records started populating as expected.  Still trying to figure out why my reverse records are not getting created but that is likely a separate issue and not a blocker at this point.

Comment: Glad to hear that, and suggest posting a new question in ServerFault if you need.

Comment: is there any way to do it on linux VM using boot script without reboot ?